# Apache/php permission problem

Tags: php, apache-http-server, permissions

[image: .]

I think it's self explaining. It says it's not writable but the permissions are correct. I'm logged as a root but it's the same for every user. So where's the problem?

Comment: OMG this is a 777, do not trust any answer containing a 777, it's like a del *.*

Comment: does the server have selinux installed/enabled?

Answer (score 1):

PHP, when running in safe mode, enforces some additional security constraints on file access, over and above underlying file-system permissions. See the note about `fopen` on [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php)

It says:

> Checks whether the directory in which the script is operating has the same UID (owner) as the script that is being executed.

You should `chown` the tmp/cache to belong to your webserver's user (usually `apache`).

Comment: it actually does something but still it doesn't work. same errors as before.